# Reaching field in axios response

Tags: javascript, fetch, axios

I'm creating little app using API TheMovie DB. My function responsible for fetching data looks like this:

```
movieSearch(term){
const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}${API_KEY}&query=${term}`);
console.log(request);
}
```

Result in console looks like this:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKrfK.jpg)
How can i reach "response" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `axios.get()` returns a Promise object (what you see in the screenshot). To get the `response` of HTTP request, you need to invoke that Promise object's `then()` function:

```
axios.get('http://<your address>')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

For more information on Promise and its usage, you can refer to [Promise - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).